# Cross domain issue with socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, coldfusion, socket.io

I'm working on a node.js application and running into an 'Access is denied' error for the socket.io.js file.

- My ColdFusion application runs on server A with domain A.com
- My Node server is on server B and domain is B.com

My ColdFusion application is trying to load the node application, but I get "access is denied" when it tries to load the socket.io.js from B.com.  This issue is only noticed in IE.

One work around is to add B.com to trusted site list on IE. Then the application loads fine.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried it on all versions of IE?

Comment: Im using different modes in IE 11.    
IE modes in 9, 8, 7 passes but 10 and 11 fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "Origin" header to the request (from A.com) and an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to the server's (B.com) response that permits cross-domain request support:

Request:

```
<cfheader name="Origin" value="#cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#">
```

Response:

```
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"> 
.. or ...
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="B.com/myfile.js,cfm,whatevs...would match the result of CGI vars above ^">
```

Comment: I keep getting access denied in socket.io.js file and on IE 10 and up.   I can pass by setting io.util.ua.hasCORS=false but then I get securityError next.  I'm looking for code that will make CORS work or bypass CORS for socket.io/node.js.  Thanks